# Finding definition of an index set $A_n$ with specific conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know how to find out the union and intersection of a predefined index set, but how about finding out the definition of a described set with specific conditions like its intersection?

E.g. Find out $$\{A_n\}_{n∈N}$$ where: $$ A_1 ⊃ A_2 ⊃ A_3 ⊃ ... $$ $$ \bigcap_{n∈N}A_n = R-Q $$

What would be the approach for this type of questions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These conditions are not enough to identify exactly one sequence of sets. You have to guess one and then show that it works.

Comment: @Gae.S. :-? How to guess?

Comment: With all your ingenuity.

Comment: This was one of my exam questions 2 days ago, and I couldn't find it out alongside 4 other questions in just 30 minutes of time that I had :( So I was curious about finding out the answer, maybe would be useful for myself @Gae.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the intersection equal to $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, you need to make sure that each $A_n$ contains every irrational number, and that each rational number is excluded from at least one $A_n$. The set of rational numbers is countably infinite, and you have countably infinitely many sets $A_n$ at your disposal, so the easiest way to do this is to use each $A_n$ to exclude a different rational number.

Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A_n=\Bbb R\setminus\{q_n\}$. That takes care of the intersection, but unfortunately, these sets aren’t nested. However, that’s easily fixed: instead of removing **one** rational to get $A_n$, remove the first $n$ rationals in the list: let $A_n=\Bbb R\setminus\{q_k:k=1,\ldots,n\}$. The intersection is still $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, and now $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if $\mathbb Q = \{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, then $$\mathbb R \setminus \{q_0\} \supseteq \mathbb R \setminus \{q_0,q_1\} \supseteq \mathbb R \setminus \{q_0,q_1,q_2\} \supseteq \cdots$$ and $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} (\mathbb R \setminus \{q_0,\dots,q_n\}) = 
\mathbb R \setminus \bigg( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\{q_0,\dots,q_n\} \bigg) = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q.$$
Also, you forgot the words "These conditions are not enough to identify exactly one sequence of sets" in the @Gae. S.'s comment. Another comment: there is no algorithm to approach this kind of questions.

This example came to my mind when I saw that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}A_n = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is equivalent to $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} (\mathbb R \setminus A_n) = \mathbb Q$, thanks to De Morgan's laws.